# Find a formula for $\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu+d\nu}$ in terms of $d\lambda/d\mu$ and $d\lambda/d\nu$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> (a) Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $(X, \mathcal{M})$. Suppose that $\nu\ll\mu$ and that R-N derivative of $f=d\nu/d\mu$ satisfies
>   $$f(x)=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x)\in (0,\infty), x\in X$$
>   Show that $\mu\ll\nu$ and find a formula for $d\mu/d\nu$(in terms of $d\nu/d\mu$)

I feel like $d\mu/d\nu=1/(d\nu/d\mu)$. But how to show that?

> (b)Now suppose that $\mu, \nu, \lambda$ are $\sigma$-finite measures on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ and that $\lambda\ll\mu,\mu$, with $d\lambda/d\mu$ and $d\lambda/d\nu\in(0,\infty)$. Find a formula for $$\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu+d\nu}$$ in terms of  $d\lambda/d\mu$ and $d\lambda/d\nu$.

By the (a), we have $d\mu/d\nu=1/(d\nu/d\mu)$. So $\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu+d\nu}=1/(d\mu/d\lambda+d\nu/d\lambda)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply these two results.

$\textbf{Result :---}$ Suppose $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite measure with $\nu\ll \mu$.

$$g\in L^1(\nu)\implies g\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\in L^1(\mu)\ \text{ and } \int gd\nu=\int g\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu.$$

$\textbf{Proof :---}$ Consider seperately $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ and then check these results hold for simple functions. Finally using monotone convergence theorem show this also hold for non-negative functions.

$\textbf{Result :---}$ In addition to the hypothesis of the previous result, also suppose $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite measure with $\mu\ll\lambda$. Then, $$\nu\ll\lambda\ \text{ and }  \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}=\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\text{ a.e. }$$

$\textbf{Proof :---}$ Take $g=\chi_E\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ in previous result.

Comment: How to use it? I have no idea.